# EXCEL VBA Check if only user click column A

Tags: excel, vba

how do I check if the user click on the column A? I tried using:

```
if selection = worksheets(Sheet1).range("A:A") then 
   *do something* 
else exit sub
end sub
```

will not work. Please guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to check in which column is currently selected range you could do it in two ways:

1. in situation when you refer to one single cell we could say that `Activecell` equals to `Selection`. Therefore you could use this code:

   ```
   If Activecell.Column = 1 then
       *do something*
   else 
       exit sub
   end sub
   ```
2. it could happened that your selection range is bigger than one single cell. If you want to check if part of it (left column) is within Column A you could use this code:

   ```
   If Selection.Columns(1).Column = 1 then
       *do something*
   else 
       exit sub
   end sub
   ```

**EDIT** after additional questions from comments below:

To include all three conditions into one check we would go this way (first option from above is good enough):

```
    If Activecell.Column = 1 And Selection.Cells.Count = 1 And Activecell.Offset(0,1) <> "" Then
        *do something*
    else 
        exit sub
    end sub
```

Comment: Basically the conditions are: (1)If the activecell.column = 1. (2)If activecell.offset(0,1) <> "". (3)If the user only select 1 cell and not multiple cell. I'm stuck at the 3rd condition. Can you help me on this 3rd condition?

Comment: add `if selection.cells.count =1 then` to check for one single cell selected :)

Comment: Can u edit your answer as a complete code for me? I cannot make it work.

Comment: My code before was If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" And Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then MsgBox ("ok") 'For testing Else End If. No wonder cannot work.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Target.Column` :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1

    End If
End Sub
```